# Show that $(\mathbb Z[x],+)$ and $(\mathbb Q_{>0},\cdot)$ are isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(\mathbb{Z}[x],+)$ be the additive group of polynomials with integer coefficients and $ (\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\cdot)$ the multiplicative group of positive rationals. Show these groups are isomorphic.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! When you post a question, please provide some context and explain what you have tried so far. Among other things, this helps to ensure that you get answers which address the specifics of your problem. For general question guidelines, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Perhaps this could be of help: Think of elements of $(\mathbb{Z}(x), +)$ as infinite tuples which are eventually zero. Explicitly, you can identify $a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^2+\cdots + a_{n} x^{n}$ with the infinite tuple $(a_{0}, a_{1}, …, a_{n}, 0, 0, …)$ where $a_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Can you think of a map that would send this element to $(\mathbb{Q}_{>}, \cdot)$? (Another hint is to consider uniqueness of prime factorization).

Comment: This question has been already asked

Answer (score 10):

One way of showing that two structures are isomorphic is to make a good choice of a third structure to which they're both isomorphic. To this end, let $G$ denote the set of all functions $f : P \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ (where $P = \{2,3,5,...\}$ is the set of all prime numbers) such that $f$ is zero for all but finitely many elements of its domain. Then $(G,+)$ is a group.

**Exercises.**

1. Show that $(ℤ[x],+)$ is isomorphic to $(G,+).$ (Straightforward.)
2. Show that $(\mathbb{Q}_{>0},\cdot)$ is isomorphic to $(G,+).$ **Hint:** Consider the function $\Pi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ defined by $\Pi(f) = \prod_{p \in P} p^{f(p)}.$

Comment: The range set of $\pi$ is $ Z^+$ but not $Q^+$, then how it can be an isomorphism

Comment: @sabeelmsk note that f(p) can be negative. This the range of Pi is much larger than just the integers.

Answer (score 2):

What things additively generate $\Bbb Z[x]$? What do we always write polynomials as sums of?

What things multiplicatively generate $\Bbb Q_{>0}$? What are positive rationals always products (and quotients) of? If it helps, consider the question for natural numbers: what kinds of things do natural numbers always factor as products of?

See if you can use these hints to describe an isomorphism $(\Bbb Z[x],+)\cong(\Bbb Q_{>0},\cdot)$. If it helps, you can try to go through a middleman, $\Bbb Z^{\bigoplus\Bbb N}=\{(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots):a_i\in\Bbb Z,\textrm{finitely many }a_i\ne0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Please provide full proof,